# Projecting multiple fields to a POJO

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

Is there a way in hibernate-search 6 to project multiple fields and map them directly to a POJO object or I should handle it by myself. I'm not sure that I understand the composite method described in the documentation. For example I can do something like that:

```
SearchResult<List<?>> result = searchSession.search(indicies)
.select(f -> f.composite(f.field("field1"), f.field("field2"), f.field("field3"),f.field("field4")))
.where(SearchPredicateFactory::matchAll)
.fetch(20)
```

And then I can manually map the returned List of fields to a POJO. But is there a more fancy way to do that without the need to manually loop through the list of fields and set them to the POJO instance?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment projecting to a POJO is only possible for fairly simple POJOs, with up to three fields, using the syntax [shown in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-composite). For more fields than that, you have to go through a `List`.

If you're using the Elasticsearch backend, you can theoretically [retrieve the document as a `JsonObject`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-extensions-elasticsearch-source) and then use Gson to map it to a POJO.

There are [plans to offer more fancy solutions](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3927), but we're not there yet.